How to use global variables across SW Components in AUTOSAR Classic
I add Port and DataElement in each SWC for SWC(SW Components) refer and modify one common variable (e.g. sensorData).
Then there are problems.
Problem 1 : Runnable in SWC need to many of RTE Read API (Rte_Read_).
Problem 2 : Only recent data received by the last RTE Read API is available.
This is the code that is currently implemented
// SWC1
#include "Rte_Swc.1"

void Runnable_Sender1(void)
{
    SensorData_t sensorData;

    Rte_Read_Swc1_RpSender2Data_SensorData(&sensorData);
    Rte_Read_Swc1_RpSender3Data_SensorData(&sensorData);
        
    sensorData.sensorId = 1;
    sensorData.sensorValue = 100; 

    Rte_Write_Swc1_PpSender1Data_SensorData(&sensorData);
}

// SWC2
#include "Rte_Swc.2"

void Runnable_Sender2(void)
{
    SensorData_t sensorData;

    Rte_Read_Swc2_RpSender1Data_SensorData(&sensorData);
    Rte_Read_Swc2_RpSender3Data_SensorData(&sensorData);
        
    sensorData.sensorId = 2;
    sensorData.sensorValue = 20

    Rte_Write_Swc2_PpSender2Data_SensorData(&sensorData);
}

// SWC3
#include "Rte_Swc.3"

void Runnable_Sender3(void)
{

    SensorData_t sensorData;
    
    Rte_Read_Swc3_RpSender1Data_SensorData(&sensorData);
    Rte_Read_Swc3_RpSender2Data_SensorData(&sensorData);
    
    sensorData.sensorId = 3;
    sensorData.sensorValue = 300; 
    
    Rte_Write_Swc3_PpSender3Data_SensorData(&sensorData);
}

I wonder if there is a good solution.
